# GuzzleHttp give me an error suddenly on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, guzzle

I suddenly had this error on my project:

```
Argument 1 passed to Vonage\Client::setHttpClient() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface, instance of GuzzleHttp\Client given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/nexmo/client-core/src/Client.php
```

Here is a little part of code in package:

```
        if (is_null($client)) {
        // Since the user did not pass a client, try and make a client
        // using the Guzzle 6 adapter or Guzzle 7 (depending on availability)
        /** @noinspection ClassConstantCanBeUsedInspection */
        if (class_exists('\GuzzleHttp\Client')) {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        } elseif (class_exists('\Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client')) {
            /** @noinspection CallableParameterUseCaseInTypeContextInspection */
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedNamespaceInspection */
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
            $client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();
        }
    }

    $this->setHttpClient($client);
```

I tried to update guzzlehttp with:
**composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle**

And I've got this error:

```
  Problem 1
    - webup/laravel-sendinblue v2.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev].
    - webup/laravel-sendinblue v2.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev].
    - webup/laravel-sendinblue v2.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.2.0, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.2 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.2.0].
    - Installation request for webup/laravel-sendinblue (locked at v2.0.3, required as 2.*) -> satisfiable by webup/laravel-sendinblue[v2.0.3].
```

I don't know what I can doing :(

Please help me to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: `webup/laravel-sendinblue` needs upgraded, v2.0.3 only supports up to guzzle v6.3.  v3.1.0 supports version 7 of guzzle.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you installing into? Normally the check works OK, but if we need to modify it we can.

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same error on Laravel 7, using Vonage. Spent evening by this. For me worked to set in .env this:

```
NEXMO_HTTP_CLIENT="Http\\Adapter\\Guzzle6\\Client"
```

In case you didn't change the config/nexmo.php it is directly used.

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I was looking for that ClientInterface and found this Guzzle6/Client

Comment: Nexo/Laravel ->Vonage migration have the same problem in 2.4.1, require this parameter for php lower than 7.4, thanks!